# Vbdotnet Substring

Tags: vb.net

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       Dim reader As StreamReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(TextBox1.Text)      
       Dim a As String
       a = reader.ReadLine     
       RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text + a
       Label5.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Substring(5, a.Substring(5, a.Length))
       reader.Close()
    End Sub
```

Hello. I am trying to read a text file and put the numbers in different variables. The textfile is like this

[IMAGE](http://postimg.org/image/9tdookgvz/)

Every time i run the code it comes out with an error. What should i do?

Comment: **What does the error say**?

Answer (score 1):

What is it that you're trying to do with this line?

```
    Label5.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Substring(5, a.Substring(5, a.Length))
```

This part: `a.Substring(5, a.Length)` returns a string, but the second argument of `Substring` expects an integer, so it is causing an error.

[Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) looks like this: `Substring(startIndex As Integer, length As Integer)`. You are trying to pass a string into the second argument.

Simply dropping the second argument from that line seems that it would do what you want it to:

```
    Label5.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Substring(5)
```

---

If these types of problems are frequently affecting you, I highly suggest you turn Option Strict on in Visual Studio. [Here are some instructions on how to do so.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311329)

Comment: I agree the second argument is the problem. If absent the all the text starting with the sixth character will be returned. The constant only makes sense if you are just doing this as an experiment/demo of an issue.

Comment: I used this 
line Label5.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Substring(5, a.Substring(5, a.Length))
in order to get a variable.
For example in the line <var>50. I want to get the 50 int and place it to label 5

Comment: @Frozen Blade: If your text file always has one line per variable, and is always preceded by '<var>' then the code I provided will work. It skips the first 5 characters and reads to the end of the line. You'll have to modify it if that's not the case, however, as rheitzman was suggesting.